# How to pass http.call results to a template?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

My `client/main.js` has the following code:

```
Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
  // counter starts at 0
  this.counter = new ReactiveVar(0);
  var token = Meteor._localStorage.getItem("token");
  var result = HTTP.call('GET', 'http://faa22147.ngrok.io/auth/users', {
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      'Authorization': "Bearer " + token
    }
  }, function (error, result) {
    if (!error) {
      console.log(result.data);
      this.users = result.data;
    }
    console.log(error.response.content);
  });
});
```

`result.data` has the object as returned from the API correctly.

The template is very simple, but the response is not being returned to the template.

```
<template name="hello">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
  {{#each users}}
    {{>user}}
  {{/each}}

</template>

<template name="user">
  {{name}}  
</template>
```

Comment: Make `this.users` a reactive var as well.

Comment: There is also the uncertainty about `this` and if `users` is accessible from template context or if you need a helper.

Comment: I tried making this.users reactive, and also tried using the helper, copying the counter() example from the starter

  users() {
    return Template.instance().users.get();
  },

and then use:
instance.users=result.data;

nothing working still

Comment: You need to `set()` it to `result.data`, assuming it is an array, not overwrite it by an array. `this.uesrs.set(result.data)`.

Comment: Thanks MasterAM and ghybs set() was right,but I also needed .bind(this) in my call... works now :D

Comment: You can use an arrow function to get rid of the need for `bind`.

Comment: Very nice, actually never used arrow function short of copying a tutorial. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template helpers are re-run when a [reactive computation is invalidated](http://blazejs.org/guide/understanding-blaze.html#Re-rendering).

A `ReactiveVar` is a reactive data source, and calling `get()` on it creates a `reactive dependency`. When this is done in the context of a template helper, it creates a reactive computation that listens to invalidation of its dependencies.

This invalidation happens when you `set()` the value to something else, and this causes the helper to re-run and the template to update.

```
Template.hello.onCreated(function() {
  this.users = new ReactiveVar(null); // (1) initialize to null, so that we can tell when loading
  const token = Meteor._localStorage.getItem("token");

  HTTP.call('GET', 'http://faa22147.ngrok.io/auth/users', {
    headers:{
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
    }}, (e, r) => {
      if (!e) {
        this.users.set(r.data); // (2) set the reactive var to trigger a reactive computation
      }
      // todo: handle error case
    });
});

Template.hello.helpers({
  users() {
    return Template.instance().users.get(); // supplies the reactive variable to the template
  },
});
```

I added a `loading...` text for the case that `users` is not yet set. When the `users` helper is invalidated (set to an array), it reruns, and `users` now is truthy, and the inner `each` is triggered.

Note that this does not handle the `error` case, so if the `HTTP` call fails, it gets stuck at `loading...`.

```handlebars
<template name="hello">
  {{#if users}}
    {{#each users}}
      {{>user}}
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    loading...
  {{/if}}
</template>
```